# C++ Template, Declaring Object without Initialising

Tags: c++, class, templates, object, types

so i have the following situation. Basically i want to know if it's possible to declare an object of a template class without knowing it's type, or is there another approach i can use for a situation like this.

```
template <class T> class SomeTemplateClass{
    vector<T> v;
}

int main(){
  --- Here is where i want to declare the object ---
  SomeTemplateClass o;
  cin >> eType;
  --- Type is not determined until some user input---
  if (eType == "int"){
        o = SomeTemplateClass<int> (size);
  } 
  else if (eType == "char") {
      o = SomeTemplateClass<char> (size);
  }
  else if (eType == "float") {
     o = SomeTemplateClass<float> (size);
  }
```

The type has to be passed as standard input as this is a requirement of the assignment.

EDIT: Ignoring everything else, my problem is that i want to create a vector of type T where T is determined at run-time via user-input. Is this possible at all, and if not what is an acceptable solution

Comment: Since templates are resolved on compile time, you can't do that. And for us to suggest the best alternative solution, you will have to provide information on why you need something like that.

Comment: if for example i had, vector <T> v , and didn't know the type of v until compile time (as it is determined from user input), could i still use templates or is this not possible.

Comment: a very wastefull solution it to create a vector of SomeTemplateClass with all  the types you need, then based on the input would delete the objects you dont need :)

Comment: templates are resolved by the *compiler*, so I think the basic answer is "no". Of course, you could use ordinary polymorphism, at the cost of an extra level of indirection. Or you could use a boost::variant.

Comment: @Koborl I understand what you want, but not why you want it. I can't see why would you need something like that. No, templates types are resolved on compile time. vector<int> and vector<float> are two different types, you can't create one object for both of them.

Comment: The only reason i need something like this is because the assignment specifically states that we must use templates and it also states that the user must be able to chose the type via text input.


Basically i have 
-----some class that contains---------

[[ vector<t> v which type isn't determined til runtime;]]

,[[some template methods that perform various operations on v ]]

Comment: @KostasRim no so wasteful if you use unions.

Comment: @Satus good point :)

Comment: @Koborl ok, so let's go to the next step.  What do you actually do with these differing vector types?  That I believe is the bigger question.  What is it you're trying to accomplish, on a high-level (without mentioning templates)?

Comment: @Koborl then the best solution for you would be to ask whoever gave you this assignment to clarify it. What you want is impossible to do with templates.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
it's basically to implement a open addressed hash table for multiple types, i.e. for int,char,string,float,double. And the operations would be things like insertion, deletion, look-up etc.

Comment: @Kobol Well, I don't see how you're going to do this assignment unless it's some sort of hybrid implementation of object oriented and templates.  It certainly can't purely be templates (but templates can play a role).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie

I think i jumped the gun a bit, it does say to make use of templates but doesn't specify where. If i use a standard class and make use of overloaded  constructors is there any way to do this. All i can think of is it keeps coming back to I don't know the type of the vector until run-time... unless i have multiple vectors for each type ready and then use the input to determine which one i use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from reading your comment I figured out you'd want something like that

```
template<typename T>
class myclass {
    vector<T> v;
... other methods
};

template<typename T>
void do_something_cool_with_myclass(myclass<T> obj)
{
   //do something with obj, type independently
}

int main() {
    ...
    cin >> type; //get type from user somehow
    switch (type) {
        case int:
         myclass<int> obj;
         do_something_cool_with_myclass<int>(obj);
        ....
    }
}
```

You don't waste memory and can process your data without knowing it's type on compile time.